# Proof that every polygon has at least 2 ears

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, computational-geometry

I had this question asked a few weeks ago and gave an argument that involved finding an ear and clipping it, professor said it was not quite the correct answer and that I lacked some insights.

How would you prove this? I'm not allowed to use the dual graph of a triangulation, because given that any polygon has at least 2 ears, then we can triangulate the polygon by ear clipping.

**So how can I prove that every polygon has at least 2 ears?**

Comment: I guess you're not limited to convex polygons?

Comment: Please write your question in the body of the question and not just in the title.

Comment: @John I don't think so but we're interested on convex polygons

Comment: TIL polygons have [ears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(geometry)#Ears).

Comment: http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1053&context=mathfacpub        POLYGONS HAVE EARS

G.H. Meisters, University of Nebraska-Lincoln

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.6038.pdf

Comment: There exist a beautiful proof. https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pigeonhole/PolygonalEars.shtml#proof

Comment: @TakahiroWaki would you mind explaining the last bit? I get lost right here: " Since the latter has n edges but there are only two triangles, "

Comment: @DavidMerinos If they have one edge, they become n triangles. Since they are n-2 triangles, they need at least two triangles with two edges (otherwise they are not n edges). Again, n-2 triangles are composite of at least two triangles with two edges and one edge's triangles.

Comment: See also https://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fcarc-diagonals1

Answer (score 0):

We can prove that any $P$ polygon with $n \geq 4$ vertices has a diagonal in its interior.

Let $x$ be a convex vertex, so the inner angle given by its two neighbours $y$ and $z$ is less than $\pi$.

If $[y,z] \in int(P)$ than we have found such a diagonal, if there are any edges intersects $[y,z]$ than we have a vertex $v$ in the interior of the $xyz$ triangle that is furthest from the line given by $yz$, (since there are finite vertices) means that $xv$ is a diagonal in $P$'s interior.

We have used that every simple polygon has a convex point; this can be proved by induction.
For $n = 3$ we have a convex point.

Assuming we have one for $n=k$

Let's see the $n=k+1$ case.

If we replace an edge with a vertex and two edges it is possible we have messed up the convex point $x$ in our polygon with $k$ vertices.

So our original convex point $x$ now not convex. Assume its original neighbour $y$ is also not convex.

If our new point $z$ is not convex, the $xyz$ triangle lies in the interior of the polygon and has at least one nonconvex point and that is a contradiction.

So from here we can find a diagonal in $P$'s interior and it divides our polygon into two other polygons with at least $3$ vertices. From here it is easy to show as we continue the search for the inner diagonals in the new polygons.

Note that a polygon with $4$ verices has at least $2$ ears.